# Interact with storefront customer's session in Shopware 6 app

Tags: shopware, shopware6, storefront

I need to retrieve a customer connected to the storefront backend side to reward him in different ways.

I created a plugin that extends the `plugin.class` of the plugins system.

It fetches the customer on the store api using the route `store-api/account/customer` then it sends to my backend its identifier. I also resolve the `shop_url` of the admin api with `window.location.protocol` and `window.location.hostname`...

This seems to me not secured or accurate (the domain can be different from the sales channel to the admin api) and I would like to know if it would be possible to fetch a secured unique customer's token that would allow me to resolve both the `shop_url` and the customer's identifier.

I cannot find anything in the documentation that would help me securing that part of my app.

Thanks.

(Edit)

Here is my actual code to fetch the customer inside the plugin:

```js
import Plugin from 'src/plugin-system/plugin.class';
import StoreApiClient from 'src/service/store-api-client.service';

const storeClient = new StoreApiClient();

const handleUser = (data, request) => {
  let unsecuredUserId = null;
  if (request.status === 200) {
    try {
      const user = JSON.parse(data);
      unsecuredUserId = user.id || null;
    } catch (e) {}
  }
  doSomethingWith(unsecuredUserId);
}

export default class SaylPlugin extends Plugin {
  init() {
    storeClient.get('store-api/account/customer', handleUser);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to get the things more secured.

My new plugin code:

```js
import Plugin from 'src/plugin-system/plugin.class';
import StoreApiClient from 'src/service/store-api-client.service';

const storeClient = new StoreApiClient();

const handleContext = (data, request) => {
  if (request.status === 200) {
    try {
      const context = JSON.parse(data);
      if (context instanceof Object) {
        resolveCustomerBackendSide(
          context.token,
          context.salesChannel.id
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
}

export default class SaylPlugin extends Plugin {
  init() {
    storeClient.get('store-api/context', handleContext);
  }
}
```

With this context I can resolve the admin api credentials backend side using the sales channel identifier that I save during the app registration process (you will have to allow sales_channel read in the app's manifest). Therefore I fetch the sales channel backend side to retrieve the `sw-access-key` header and I can finally fetch the store-api backend side to retrieve the customer in a secured way (the `token` that you get after fetching the `store-api/context` can be used as `sw-context-token` header.

Answer (score 1):

You have access to the customer object in the twig template, given the user is currently logged-in. Using this fact you can pass customer data to your plugin using data attributes. The plugin base offers automatic parsing of options based on the naming convention.

```html
{% set myPluginData = {
    customerId: context.customer.id
} %}

<div data-my-custom-plugin="true"
     data-my-custom-plugin-options="{{ myPluginData|json_encode }}">
</div>
```

```js
class MyCustomPlugin extends Plugin {
    init() {
        if (this.options.customerId) {
            // do something when the customer is logged in
        }
    }

    // ...
}

PluginManager.register('MyCustomPlugin', MyCustomPlugin, '[data-my-custom-plugin]');
```

Comment: Actually this does not answer my question since I don't want to send the customerId to the backend. I need to resolve the appId and the customerId backend side.

Comment: Then update your question with some code samples of your app. As it stands you're referring to an app with a storefront javascript plugin. In that case this is the recommended way to pass data to the plugin. It's very hard to grasp what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Actually I need to bridge the store API and the admin API. This to resolve the customer on my backend using the admin API. And for this purpose I need the shop_id. I will update my question but my sample is actually very limited.